# How to exit onBackPressed method in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exit, onbackpressed

I have developed an android apps that have a splash screen and a login page. The problem is when a user give credential and pressed log in button it open controlActivity. but when I pressed back button, I navigate to login page again If I pressed back button again I navigate to splash screen. **How can I stop navigating to previous page, when user press back button then app should exit?**

Answer (score 1):

### Why does it happen ?

---

This is happening because whenever you open another activity from intent, it creates it over it.

### How to solve the problem?

---

1. You can add a flag like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

OR

2. You can finish it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

If you want to close the app `onBackPressed`, you can override the method. Add this to your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Doing this, the app will be closed on back pressed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a flag in the activity you want to be forgotten.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: it stop going back but app doesn't close I need to exit onBackPressed also

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Sambhav Khandelwal should solve your problem. In your splash screen you need to do add flags with intent like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class); //assuming your splash screen name as SplashScreenActivity and login as LoginActivity
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or you can do without flags like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```